# exists? returns false when model object actually exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exists

Im somewhat struggling when using rails `exists?` method. Actually I'm trying to check if a `Location` with given `longitude` and `latitude` exists. My code looks like this

```rb
Location.exists?(longitude: 9.81639, latitude: 52.4003)
Location Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `locations`  WHERE `locations`.`longitude` = 9.81639 AND `locations`.`latitude` = 52.4003 LIMIT 1
=> false
```

Now this always returns false even when an object with this exact data exists.

When using

```rb
Location.exists?(country: "Germany")
```

I get the following output and everything is working just fine. I get the desired results.

```rb
Location.where(country: "Germany").first.attributes
Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `locations`.* FROM `locations`  WHERE `locations`.`country` = 'Germany'  ORDER BY `locations`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
{"id"=>1, "spot_id"=>nil, "street"=>"Garbeweg 2", "zip"=>"30655", "city"=>"Hanover", "country"=>"Germany", "longitude"=>9.81639, "latitude"=>52.4003, "created_at"=>Wed, 09 Jul 2014 13:08:48 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 09 Jul 2014 13:08:48 UTC +00:00}
```

I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: Some additional output

```
Location.where(longitude: 9.81639, latitude: 52.4003).first
Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `locations`.* FROM `locations`  WHERE `locations`.`longitude` = 9.81639 AND `locations`.`latitude` = 52.4003  ORDER BY `locations`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

When checking the equality manually, I get this:

```rb
l = Location.first
{"id"=>1, "spot_id"=>nil, "street"=>"Garbeweg 2", "zip"=>"30655", "city"=>"Hanover", "country"=>"Germany", "longitude"=>9.81639, "latitude"=>52.4003, "created_at"=>Wed, 09 Jul 2014 13:08:48 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 09 Jul 2014 13:08:48 UTC +00:00}
l.longitude == 9.81639 && l.latitude == 52.4003
=> true
```

Comment: show me the output `Location.where(country: "Germany").first.attributes`.

Comment: What are the data types of 'longitude' and 'latitude' in data base and please give the the actual record of location which has (longitude: 9.70758, latitude: 57.8985) data...

Comment: @Sanket That's my question too. :-)

Comment: I've edited the question with the actual output. longitude and latitude are both float data types as I am using `geokit-rails` gem.

Comment: Show us `Location.where(longitude: 9.81639, latitude: 52.4003).first`

Comment: if longitude and lattitude columns are floating point, you might have floating point comparison issues. Consider making them strings instead.

Comment: if `Location.where(longitude: 9.81639, latitude: 52.4003).first` gives nil, there is no reason why `Location.exists?(longitude: 9.81639, latitude: 52.4003)` will give you true....! ONLY the second query, that gives you a record, should return true.

Comment: I understand this, but the Location with the given longitude and latitude actually does exist! I just don't get why I can't get the location using long/lat. Especially when equality check returns true?! (see my edit on this)

Comment: @BenLime - the equality checks you make (which return true) are on the _ruby_ side, the query, though, runs on the _database_ side. In the middle the values are converted from ruby types to db types and back. There is no guarantee (in floating point values especially) that they keep their exact values.

Comment: see what this gives you: `l = Location.first` and then `Location.exists?(longitude: l.longitude, latitude: l.latitude)`